# How to add an entry to a database table for a combination of two tables

Tags: java, sql, spring, database, postgresql

I have `User` and `Customer` classes that work with relationship `@OneToOne`. Accordingly, `Customer` has a `POST-method`, when executed, I create an entry in the `user` table, and then in the `customer` table. I don’t know how to connect them in the table, that is, in the `customer` table in the `user_id` field, I don’t know how to put the `id` of the `user` I just created?

All `User` fields belong to `Customer` too.

I use `Spring-MVC` + `Hibernate` + `Jpa` + `PostgreSQL`.

This is my first big project with Spring.

User:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.model;

import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@ApiModel
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "pg_user", schema = "public")
public class User {

    public User() { // Пустой конструктор для Hibernate

    }

    public User(String name, String lastName, String role,
                String login, String password) { // Базовый конструктор

        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.role = role;
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }


    // Поля
    private @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
}
```

Customer:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;
import com.tinychiefdelights.repository.CustomerRepository;
import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFound;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFoundAction;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer", schema = "public")
public class Customer {

    public Customer() { // Пустой конструктор для Hibernate

    }


    // Поля

    // name, lastName, login, password берем от класса User через связи;

    private @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "wallet")
    private double wallet;


    //Relationships
    //
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id") // Join without Customer in User class
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private User user;

    //Лист заказов
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore // Таким образом я предотвратил рекурсию
    private List<Order> orderList;
}
```

Customer Service:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.service;

import com.tinychiefdelights.model.Customer;
import com.tinychiefdelights.model.User;
import com.tinychiefdelights.repository.CustomerRepository;
import com.tinychiefdelights.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class CustomerService extends UserService {


    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    private UserRepository userRepository;


    @Autowired
    public void setUserRepository(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setCustomerRepository(CustomerRepository customerRepository) {
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }



    // Методы
    //
    public Customer addCustomer(User newUser, Customer newCustomer){
        userRepository.save(newUser);
        return customerRepository.save(newCustomer);
    }
```

Customer Controller:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.controller;

import com.tinychiefdelights.exceptions.NotFoundException;
import com.tinychiefdelights.model.Customer;
import com.tinychiefdelights.model.User;
import com.tinychiefdelights.repository.CustomerRepository;
import com.tinychiefdelights.service.CustomerService;
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@Api(value = "Работа с Заказчиком", tags = {"Заказчик"})
@RestController
public class CustomerController {

    //Constructor
    //
    @Autowired
    public CustomerController(CustomerRepository customerRepository, CustomerService customerService) {
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
        this.customerService = customerService;
    }


    // Fields
    //Injects into constructor
    //
    private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    private CustomerService customerService;



    // Aggregate Root
    @GetMapping("/customers")
    List<Customer> all(){
        return customerRepository.findByUserRole("customer");
    }

    @PostMapping("/customers")
    Customer addCustomer(User newUser, @RequestBody Customer newCustomer){
        return customerService.addCustomer(newUser, newCustomer);
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to synchronize the association between the entities:

```
public Customer addCustomer(User newUser, Customer newCustomer) {
    newCustomer.setUser(newUser);
    return customerRepository.save(newCustomer);
}
```

And cascade the changes to the `User`:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private User user;
```

Comment: @ArturVartanyan glad to hear that, have a great day!